# Classicthesis, remove [date, time - version #]

Tags: classicthesis

How to remove [date-time - version #] line at the bottom of every page from Classicthesis? Classicthesis version is 4.1.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: @Manuel, thank you very much. What an easy solution :-)

Comment: @Manuel, `[final]` option declaration is enough. Thank you again.

Comment: Okey, I just flagged it as a duplicate, but may be I can add the answer of using `\documentclass[final]{…}`… I don't know what should I do.